# Angular 2 Routing Does Not Work When Deployed to Http Server

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-routing, angular-cli, angular2-template

I am going to develop a simple Angular 2 application. I have created a project with routing, using Angular CLI and added several components to the app using 'ng generate component ' command. Then I specified routing in the **app-routing.module.ts** as following.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { SpecialpageComponent } from './specialpage/specialpage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
    {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'specialpage',
    component: SpecialpageComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts** is as following.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { SpecialpageComponent } from './specialpage/specialpage.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    UserComponent,
    SpecialpageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have not added any modifications for the other components. 
Then I deployed the application using 'ng serve' command and the app works fine with the links. 
Eg: http://localhost:4200/about

[image]

But when I deploy the project in http-server, the links do not work as expected. I deployed the app using 'http-server ./dist'  command and the app gets deployed fine, but the links do not work. When I go to 'http://localhost:4200/about', it gives 404 error.

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? Why 'ng-serve' works and 'http-server' does not work?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have uploaded my project to [github](https://github.com/kinathru/multiple-page-app).

Comment: Try `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],`. If it works this way, you need to enable HTML5 pushState on your production server.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I tried, but no luck

Comment: Also try adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to this route `path: '',`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for your comment, but I'm unable to get get work yet

Comment: Have you tried `127.0.0.1:8081/about` with `useHash: true` or `127.0.0.1:8081/#/about` (or whatever the URL looks like exactly after you navigate to the about page)?

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, Yes you are correct. When I use 'useHash:true' and then when i go to the links like 'http://172.16.3.77:8081/#/about', they work without an issue. Is there a way to remove the # here?

Comment: Yes, do not use `useHash:true` :D. As I said in my initial comment. You have to configure the server to support HTML5 pushState. `useHash:true` was only to debug the cause of the issue.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ah.. my bad. Actually I'm pretty new to all this. Anyway, according to your answer, what i feel is that I can't host my angular cli app in a normal hosting service. What is your opinion on that? I did some reading on pushstate supported servers. So ngserve supports push state and it's because  my project works fine with ngserve. But http-server does not support pushstate.

Comment: If the server doesn't support it then it's probably not worth trying. Usually it's quite easy for a server to support it. It just needs to return `index.html` for any request that points to a non-existing resource. I have seen client-only solutions but never had a closer look and don't know about disadvantages or if this really works.

Comment: This is going to sound like a silly question, but did you actually run `ng build` before trying all of this?

Comment: @R.Richards.. :D yeah I did. But couldn't get it working yet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thank you for your invaluable information regarding this matter. I will try to find a solution for this. Thanks again

Comment: Did you find out the solution. i have same issue.

Answer (score 54):

This problem is solved by implementing `HashLocationStrategy` which adds `#` to all your routes. You achieve this by adding `HashLocationStrategy` to `AppModule` `providers`.

```js
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
```

and add the corresponding import

```js
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

This will solve your problem.

And if you don't want to use the `HashLocationStrategy`, you can use the [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy), and so your Angular app will not show  Hash in the URL.

Comment: I have same issue and I also have this in my app.modules.ts. I am not getting any 404 error. After app component init method nothing is loading as if my routes are not working. ng serve works fine but my localhost not..

Comment: Thank you! helped me. But is it ok to always show a hashtag in the deployed websites urls? Hmm

Comment: @ninjaxlite I Updated my answer if you don't want to show `Hashtag` in URLs

Comment: I feel like this shouldn't have to be a thing. Fix this Google. Change the construct of the entire internet to appease me.

Comment: This. I've tried all kinds of things to get it to run both on my nginx and IIS  - to no avail. Until I came across this one. Wouldn't we all want angular to use the HashLocationStrategy by default? Or, even farther, it shouldn't even be an option NOT to use it?

Comment: Thank You...So much

Comment: just a small thing edit PahtLocationStrategy to PathLocationStrategy on second last line :)

Comment: For me, HashLocationStrategy worked absolutely fine but not PathLocationStrategy.

Comment: Thank you, This solved my issue also.

Answer (score 24):

This is because http-server does not support **fallback** like lite-server or web pack-dev server. This is why it shows **404 not found**.
There are two solution to resolve this issue:

1. you can use **HashLocationStrategy** like mentioned above.
2. If you are deploying it to Apache or IIS server then you can simply add configurations as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)!

**Note: For development you can use lite-server.**

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 14):

I've resolved this problem with adding this in AppModule Providers:

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
```

and importing

```
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

Then I created .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Everything works great without # in URLs :)

Comment: Where i have to add .htaccess file?

Comment: @jaykhatri In main directory (there where Angular app is) on your web server. It's probably public_html.

Answer (score 10):

It will be solved in this way:

**Case-1: For version less than Angular 5.1**

1) Use **HashLocationStrategy** like mentioned below:
In **AppModule** do the following.

1.1) `import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';`

1.2) `providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]`

**Case-2: For version equal or more than Angular 5.1**

2.1) Angular has introduced this property **onSameUrlNavigation** for overcoming refresh issue on the server.

2.2) Add  **onSameUrlNavigation** to the `RouterModule.forRoot` in **imports array** .

a) In Application main routing module, i,e app.routing.module.ts / app.routing.ts add the property

See below:

```
@ngModule({

    imports: 
    [
       RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})
    ],

    exports: [RouterModule],
 });
```

Hope it help somebody.

Answer (score 6):

It will happen because it goes to find a page **about** which is not there inside at all hence 404. Possible options:

1. If you want to go with http-server then use a proxy which will redirect everything to http://localhost:your-port.

   Option:
   `-P` or `--proxy` Proxies all requests which can't be resolved locally to the given url. e.g.: `-P http://someurl.com`
2. Don't use express at all. Create your own http-server using express & Redirect everything to index.html

   Assuming public is your folder where u keep all transpiled things.

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   var path = __dirname + '/public';
   var port = 8080;

   app.use(express.static(path));
   app.get('*', function(req, res) {
       res.sendFile(path + '/index.html');
   });
   app.listen(port);
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not get you quite well. I'm really a newbie to Angular. I'm not doing anything complex here. An regarding your first option, I tried to host my server and I accessed the URL without a port. Only the root URL works. Cannot navigate into other links.

Comment: `http-server --port 4200 -P http://someurl.com` raise an infinite loop in my case

Answer (score 5):

If you, like me, want to make no code changes at all, simply use this instead:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server

Answer (score 3):

**For Apache server:**

*in the Production servers*

Add or create ".htaccess" file into the project root, add a rewrite rule to the .htaccess file as shown

```
RewriteEngine On
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this issue and found a solution that does not require HashLocationStrategy solution.

Issue is, a server like tomcat looks for a actual folder (for eg : /about ) which does not exist in angular app, as its a single page application. So every request needs to be redirected to index.html.

Easiest way to fix this issue is to add the following java class and override **addResourceHandlers**() method like below:

```
@Configuration
class WebMVCCustomConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static").resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) {
                    String path = "static/";
                    path += (resourcePath.contains(".") && !resourcePath.equals("index.html")) ? resourcePath : "index.html";

                    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(path);
                    return resource.exists() ? resource : null;
                }
            });
    }
  }
```

This will fix all the issues and this solution does not exist anywhere.

Comment: Good to know that there is solution like this, but I think is better to you use mechanisms provided by angular like that one which is mentioned above -> HashLocationStrategy. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation at https://angular.io/guide/deployment (Apache, you could also look for nginx)
You need to point the server to index.html using the .htaccess file as

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

### For Apache Server

- Create a file name `.htaccess`
- Edit that file and write `index.html` instead of `index.php`
- For those who dont have any code, can write the code below in your  `.htaccess` file :

  `RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html`
- This code might not work for SSL certificate - contact your hosting provider OR visit https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html to refer to docs.

Answer (score 1):

You should try specifying the url in the build from the point the app should initialize:

```
Ng build --prod --base-href="http://your.url.com/subdirectory/etc"
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact reason why this particular issue is being faced is because of your server settings.

So when you implement the application there are certain steps that you will have to take.
One of the essential steps is to mark a particular segment of your path say:
 http://domain-name/main
where **main** being the path segment must be used as the identifier in your server settings say your **server.js** or **app.js** when it comes to a node backend or a **webconfig** file for IIS and Tomcat deployment.

The reason for marking a particular segment is so that when the server receives any request with that particular segment + additional you reroute it to your application in www or public folder for the angular router to kick in.

This process is known as **url rewriting**.
Hence if the web server or the app server depending on the application size is not under your control then please use **hashLocationStratergy** else it is always neat to use **pathLocationStartergy** as it is helpful when it comes to history tracking and other aesthetic and performance benefits.

To read more on this you can visit these links:

**For IIS**: https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

Answer (score 0):

Add a dot in your base href strings.

Correct

```
<base href="./home">
```

Wrong

```
<base href="/home">
```

http://www.wisdomofjim.com/blog/solved-problems-with-resource-loading-failures-when-deploying-angular-2-webapps-live

Answer (score 0):

If you use href, change them to routerlink.

Answer (score -1):

```
export const routes: Routes =[
   **{ path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},**
     { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
     { path: 'user',  component: UserComponent},
     { path: 'specialpage',  component: SpecialpageComponent},
     { path: '**',  component: ErrorComponent}
    ];
```

Look at the content of blockquote.
And then you give the name of "HttpModule" at `providers:[]` in app.module.ts

Thanks.

Comment: @C.Peterscu I did as you have mentioned. But I couldn't get it work. I uploaded my project to https://github.com/kinathru/multiple-page-app.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it while registering your RouterModule.forRoot, you can pass a second object with propert {useHash: true} like the below :

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {appRoutes} from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   imports: [BrowserModule],
   RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes , {useHash: true})],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: i have the same problem but the solution does not work

Comment: I have same problem. ng serve works good but when I deploy to my local, localhost/ doesnot work

Comment: don't forget to use the hash in your url when you test it, like: http://127.0.0.1/#/home

Answer (score -1):

Change your index.html

```
<base href="/">
 to 
<base href="./">
```

Because we are using Tomcat we have mentioned this(.) 
for Routing is based on this(/) So same like http-server

I mean running normally ng serve you have seen only 
`http://localhost:4200/`

but run in server you have put your build into(dist) in webapps

so its come like

```
http://localhost:8080/dist/
```

so you need to add `<base href="./">`

i think this is the problem for you may be solved.

Answer (score -1):

in the project folder create .htaccess file an then write

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

follow this link:
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score -1):

I used lite-server.

```
npm i -D  lite-server
```

then in my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
   "ci:serve:employee-onboarding": "ng build --prod --project=employee-onboarding && lite-server -c lite-server-config.json"
}
```

to run it:  `npm run ci:serve:employee-onboarding`

my lite-server-config.json file looks like this

```
{
  "port": 4201,
  "server": { "baseDir": "dist/apps/employee-onboarding" }
}
```