# Angular 17 after build ssr I don't have the actual content of pages

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular17

After build and serve the application I open the source code and I find the header and footer elements and router-outlet in between but without any content..
What is the problem here? How to get the whole page in the source code?

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: @Don like what?

Comment: @Don https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368564/angular-universal-not-rendering-content-inside-of-router-outlet
actually, this the same problem but in angular 17 I don't know how to fix it..